# How do I add a column to a data.table and return multiple columns without modifying underlying data?

Tags: r, dataframe, data.table

I have the following `data.table` in `R`

```
dt <- data.table(gender = c("Male", "Female"), Prop = c(0.49, 0.51))
#   gender Prop
# 1:   Male  0.49
# 2: Female  0.51
```

I want to calculate a `Freq = Prop * 1000` column and then return just the `gender` and `Freq` columns. How can I do this in a single line of code and **without** explicitly referring to the `gender` column and **without** modifying `dt`?

The best I can manage is:

```
onsdist$gender[, c(.SD, Freq = Prop * 1000)][, .SD, .SDcols = - "Prop"]
#    gender Freq1 Freq2
# 1:   Male   490   490
# 2: Female   510   510
```

but I've ended up with a duplicated `Freq` column.

(The reason I don't want to refer to `gender` is because it changes across `data.table`s. The reason I don't want to modify `dt` is because I need to re-use the original version later).

Answer (score 5):

**1)** Use transform with Prop = NULL

```
dt[, transform(.SD, Freq = Prop * 1000, Prop = NULL)]
##    gender Freq
## 1:   Male  490
## 2: Female  510
```

**2)** or this variation

```
transform(dt, Freq = Prop * 1000, Prop = NULL)
##    gender Freq
## 1:   Male  490
## 2: Female  510
```

**3)** We can speed it up substantially by just replacing transform with ftransform found in the collapse package.

```
library(collapse)
dt[, ftransform(.SD, Freq = Prop * 1000, Prop = NULL)]
```

**4)** Similarly

```
library(collapse)
ftransform(dt, Freq = Prop * 1000, Prop = NULL)
```

### Benchmark

Using the data in the question we see that (4) above, labelled ex4 below, which uses ftransform from collapse without [.data.table is much faster than the others above.

```
library(collapse)
library(data.table)
library(microbenchmark)

microbenchmark(
    ex1 = dt[, transform(.SD, Freq = Prop * 1000, Prop = NULL)],
    ex2 = transform(dt, Freq = Prop * 1000, Prop = NULL),
    ex3 = dt[, ftransform(.SD, Freq = Prop * 1000, Prop = NULL)],
    ex4 = ftransform(dt, Freq = Prop * 1000, Prop = NULL)
)

Unit: microseconds
 expr      min       lq       mean    median       uq      max neval  cld
  ex1 1847.601 1927.402 2046.04098 2015.4015 2093.251 2706.200   100    d
  ex2  959.700 1000.701 1074.93098 1046.1510 1122.601 1606.201   100  b  
  ex3 1048.201 1090.351 1139.57598 1121.6005 1174.201 1381.602   100   c 
  ex4   68.401   85.551   93.08802   89.2515  100.551  168.400   100 a
```

Comment: Added code replacing transform with ftransform from collapse.

Answer (score 3):

We can use the `data.table` syntax to get the output format

```
dt[, c(.SD, .(Freq = Prop * 1000)), .SDcols = -"Prop"]
```

-output

```
   gender Freq
1:   Male  490
2: Female  510
```

Answer (score 1):

**Another solution**

```
dt[, .(dt[, 1], Freq = Prop * 1000)]

   gender Freq
1:   Male  490
2: Female  510
```

**Some benchmark of the options given in all answers**

Note that I increased the sample data quite a bit, but I was just curious about the differences between the methods for other data sets as well.

Transform is very slow here and not recommended, the other methods are quite similar and the power of .SD and .SDcols are the fastest, although in this case, keeping all your rows and do not update anything by reference using the first method is hardly slower.

```
set.seed(42)

dt <- data.table(
  gender = rep(LETTERS[1:25], 40000),
  Prop = runif(n = 1000000))

library(rbenchmark)

benchmark(
  "dt[, .(dt[, 1], Freq = Prop * 1000)]" = {
    dt[, .(dt[, 1], Freq = Prop * 1000)]
  },
  "dt[, c(.SD, .(Freq = Prop * 1000)), .SDcols = 1]" = {
    dt[, c(.SD, .(Freq = Prop * 1000)), .SDcols = 1]
  },
  "dt[, c(.SD, .(Freq = Prop * 1000)), .SDcols = -\"Prop\"]" = {
    dt[, c(.SD, .(Freq = Prop * 1000)), .SDcols = -"Prop"]
  },
  "dt[, transform(.SD, Freq = Prop * 1000, Prop = NULL)]" = {
    dt[, transform(.SD, Freq = Prop * 1000, Prop = NULL)]
  },
  "transform(dt, Freq = Prop * 1000, Prop = NULL)" = {
    transform(dt, Freq = Prop * 1000, Prop = NULL)
  },
  replications = 1000,
  columns = c("test", "replications", "elapsed", "relative")
)

#                                                     test replications elapsed relative
# 1                   dt[, .(dt[, 1], Freq = Prop * 1000)]         1000   18.66    1.112
# 3 dt[, c(.SD, .(Freq = Prop * 1000)), .SDcols = -"Prop"]         1000   17.02    1.014
# 2       dt[, c(.SD, .(Freq = Prop * 1000)), .SDcols = 1]         1000   16.78    1.000
# 4  dt[, transform(.SD, Freq = Prop * 1000, Prop = NULL)]         1000  333.51   19.875
# 5         transform(dt, Freq = Prop * 1000, Prop = NULL)         1000  329.41   19.631
```

**Sidenote**

Keep in mind that creating the column by reference is like a 5-fold faster
`dt[, Freq := Prop * 1000]` and OP uses the argument the table is re-used later. I would suggest always to do all calculations and preparations by reference on the table when it gains in speed. You can always subset your output from there.

```
#                                               test replications elapsed relative
# 1             dt[, .(dt[, 1], Freq = Prop * 1000)]         1000   16.25    5.783
# 2 dt[, c(.SD, .(Freq = Prop * 1000)), .SDcols = 1]         1000   13.33    4.744
# 3                         t[, Freq := Prop * 1000]         1000    2.81    1.000
```